# Why is there no text on the screen when i go onto the localhost link

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    fs.readFile('home.html', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404);
        }
        else {
            res.write(data);
        }
    });
    res.end();
});

server.listen(port, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port + ' at http://localhost:' + port);
    }
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    Hello

</body>
</html>
```

when i run this and go onto the local server there is no text on the screen even thought it should say 'Hello' as thats what ive wrote in the home.html file

ive just installed node js today and dont know how it works much but i still think that this should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are ending the response before writing the data.

here is a full working code:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    fs.readFile('home.html', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404);
        }
        else {
            res.write(data);
        }
    res.end();
    });
});

server.listen(port, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port + ' at http://localhost:' + port);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You are calling [res.end](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#responseenddata-encoding-callback) outside your `fs.readFile` callback which is signaling the end of the request, and the it sends a response to the user before you finish reading/writing the file

```
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile("./home.html", function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      console.log(data);
      res.write(data);
    }
    res.end();
  });
});
```